# How to move files from specific subdirectories to a subdirectory in base directory of a directory tree?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

The base directory has about 20 subdirectories. Each subdirectory has many files. I need to move all the files from specific subdirectories to a newly created subdirectory in base directory at once.

For example I have in base directory `D:\Documents` the following directories:

```
D:\Documents\12345\data\images\
D:\Documents\12345\test\
D:\Documents\12345\documents\
```

I need to move all the files under `images` into newly to create directory `D:\Documents\images` in base directory.

Can you please help me in this?

Comment: Helping means that you tried something on your own; but all you seem to do is requesting some code for free. Please read the [tour] and learn [ask] here!

Comment: To clarify, do you (1) need to move all files from exactly one directory into another directory as in your example, or do you (2) need to move all files from multiple subdirectories. If (2), is there a pattern in the name or contents of the specific subdirectories you need to move?

Answer (score 0):

This small batch file makes the job:

```
@echo off
md D:\Documents\images 2>nul
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir D:\Documents\* /A-D /B /S 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /B /I /R /C:D:\\Documents\\..*\\images\\ 2^>nul') do (
    move /Y "%%I" "D:\Documents\images\%%~nxI"
    rd "%%~dpI" 2>nul
)
```

The batch file first creates the target directory with suppressing the error message output by **MD** if this directory already exists. It is expected by this batch file that it is possible to create this directory and move the files into this directory without any additional checks.

Command **DIR** searches in `D:\Documents` and all it subdirectories because of `/S` for just files because of `/A-D` (attribute not directory) and outputs them in bare format because of `/B` which means just the file name with file extension and in this case also with full path because of `/S`.

It is possible that **DIR** cannot find any file in entire `D:\Documents` directory tree. The error message output in this case to handle **STDERR** is suppressed by redirecting it to device **NUL** using `2>nul` after command **DIR**.

This output by **DIR** is redirected as input for command **FINDSTR** used as filter. It runs a regular expression find searching for lines starting with `D:\Documents\` having at least one more character before `\images\` must be found too. So it ignores the files in directory `D:\Documents\images\` in case of this directory already exists with files on starting the batch file. But it does not filter out files in for example `D:\Documents\12345\data\images\Subfolder\` as this regular expression does not check if `\images\` is found at end of path.

It is possible that **FINDSTR** does not find any line (file name) matching the regular expression. The error message output in this case is suppressed by using `2>nul` after command **FINDSTR**.

The command line with **DIR** and **FINDSTR** is executed by **FOR** in a separate command process started with `cmd.exe /C` in background without a visible window. For that reason the redirection operators `>` and `|` must be escaped with `^` to be interpreted first as literal characters by the Windows command interpreter on parsing the entire **FOR** command line before execution of **FOR**.

The lines output by the command line with **DIR** and **FINDSTR** to handle **STDOUT** in separate command process is captured by **FOR** and then processed line by line. With `delims=` the default behavior of splitting each line up into tokens using space and horizontal tab as delimiters is disabled by specifying an empty delimiters list.

The command **MOVE** moves the found file to `D:\Documents\images\` with overwriting a file with same name in that directory.

The command **RD** removes the directory of just moved file if this directory is empty now after moving the file. Otherwise on directory not yet being empty an error message is output by command **RD** to handle **STDERR** which is suppressed using once again `2>nul`.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `md /?`
- `move /?`
- `rd /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).